# Remove NULL in desc date ordering

Tags: python, django

I have the following query:

```
 tasks.order_by('order_item__due_date')
```

However, the first results that show have due_date = NULL.

How would I do the ordering such that the due_date must first be non-null, and then order by date. Something like:

```
tasks.order_by('order_item__due_date=not null', 'order_item__due_date')
```

Note that I do not want to filter out any results. I just want to push null results to the end. The equivalent of doing this:

```
  tasks.filter(order_item__due_date__isnull=False).order_by('due_date)
+ tasks.filter(order_item__due_date__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tasks.filter(order_item__due_date__isnull=False).order_by('order_item__due_date')
```

[`isnull` QuerySet method documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull)

Comment: No, I need to **order** by first the due date. I don't want to exclude any results.

Comment: Have you tried to do descending ordering: `tasks.order_by('-order_item__due_date')`: note the dash before

Comment: I need ascending ordering...but NULL due dates at the end.

Comment: You can't do it afaik without using the two queries like you've stated (or a manual sort)